# Как можно вывести поля таблицы в виде заголовков?

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

У меня в MS SQL Server есть подобного рода таблица

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли вывести в запросе значения столбца "Дата" в виде заголовков?
Я хочу, чтобы получился такой вариант при выполнении запроса
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно ли сделать это каким-либо образом?

Comment: лучше делайте это на клиенте. Это на порядок проще. В MS SQL есть pivot но ему все равно надо явно указать все колонки, которые хотите получить. Т.е. вы должны заранее знать все даты. Так же можно делать динамическим sql: получить список дат, после чего на основе него сформировать текст SQL-запроса, где в pivot все эти даты будут указаны и выполнить этот запрос

Answer (score 1):

Реализация предложенного колегами подхода:

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTable (Date_T datetime, Count_T int)

INSERT #MyTable 
VALUES
('2018-02-22',3), 
('2018-03-01',6),
('2018-03-08',9), 
('2018-03-15',12),
('2018-03-22',14), 
('2018-03-29',16), 
('2018-04-05',17), 
('2018-04-12',20)
```

Нам нужны две переменные, одна для динамической части (@SQL_Code), другая будет содержать заголовки столбцов (@Date_String).

```
DECLARE @Date_String nvarchar(max), @SQL_Code nvarchar(max)

SELECT @Date_String = STUFF((
SELECT ',[' +left(convert(nvarchar,Date_T,120),10)+']' 
FROM #MyTable
ORDER BY Date_T
FOR XML PATH ('')
),1,1,'')
```

Список столбцов получен, реализовываем динамический [PIVOT](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017).

```
SELECT @SQL_Code = 
'
SELECT '+@Date_String+'
FROM #MyTable
PIVOT(
SUM(Count_T)
FOR Date_T
IN ('+@Date_String+'))as pvt
'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL_Code

DROP TABLE #MyTable
```